# Android 4.3 BLE - Attempt to connect to bonded device fails

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am attempting to connect to a previously bonded (paired) device using the android 4.3 ble api's.  When I attempt to connect, I receive the following:

> 08-21 22:05:30.506    6337-6337/com.phonehalo.itemtracker
>   D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: D6:92:2D:09:0C:19, auto: false
>   08-21 22:05:30.506    6337-6337/com.phonehalo.itemtracker
>   D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() 08-21 22:05:30.516
>   6337-6337/com.phonehalo.itemtracker D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() -
>   UUID=c624d17a-e5a1-4f8a-87d1-fe87f034fe43 08-21 22:05:30.516
>   4735-5933/? D/BtGatt.GattService: registerClient() -
>   UUID=c624d17a-e5a1-4f8a-87d1-fe87f034fe43 08-21 22:05:30.516
>   4735-5933/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_register_app 08-21 22:05:30.516 
>   4735-5714/? D/BtGatt.btif: btgattc_handle_event: Event 1000 08-21
>   22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack
>   failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with
>   GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif:
>   Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/?
>   E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516
>   4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21
>   22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack
>   failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with
>   GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif:
>   Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/?
>   E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516
>   4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21
>   22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack
>   failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with
>   GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif:
>   Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/?
>   E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516
>   4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21
>   22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack
>   failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with
>   GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.516    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif:
>   Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.526    4735-5747/?
>   E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.526
>   4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21
>   22:05:30.526    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack
>   failed. 08-21 22:05:30.526    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with
>   GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.526    4735-5747/? E/bt-btif:
>   Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.526    4735-5747/?
>   E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21 22:05:30.526
>   4735-5747/? E/bt-btif: Register with GATT stack failed. 08-21
>   22:05:30.526    4735-5714/? D/BtGatt.btif: btif_gattc_upstreams_evt:
>   Event 0 08-21 22:05:30.526    4735-5714/? E/BtGatt.btif:
>   bta_to_btif_uuid: Unknown UUID length 54794! 08-21 22:05:30.526
>   4735-5714/? D/BtGatt.GattService: onClientRegistered() -
>   UUID=00000000-4090-9f08-ffff-fe585d8b1751, clientIf=0 08-21
>   22:05:30.526    4735-5714/? E/BtGatt.ContextMap: Context not found for
>   UUID 00000000-4090-9f08-ffff-fe585d8b1751

Comment: Which device? Nexus 4? I've had similar issues but with a patched Nexus 10 (no official support yet).

Comment: Did you ever find out why this happened?